# MS Outlook versions for corporate users

Tags: email

I am trying to find what proportion of ***corporate*** Outlook users use which desktop version of MS Outlook or Office 365.

That's it, really. Does anyone know?

Comment: microsoft knows.

Comment: not an answer, but this is pretty useful for learning (Windows) market share http://gs.statcounter.com/os-version-market-share/windows/desktop/worldwide (also can drill down to country). But this is based on http user agents, so it's not likely to get similar data for Outlook or Office, where every aspect is controlled by MS (server, client, app store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://www.skyhighnetworks.com/cloud-security-blog/7-charts-reveal-the-meteoric-rise-of-office-365/) is undated, but Google returns it from a search of the last year. It says

> Today, one out of every five corporate employees uses an Office 365 cloud service